# Why do GeneratorExit and StopIteration have different base classes?

Tags: python, exception, python-internals

I was taking a look at the hierarchy of the built-in python exceptions, and I noticed that `StopIteration` and `GeneratorExit` have different base classes:

```
BaseException
 +-- SystemExit
 +-- KeyboardInterrupt
 +-- GeneratorExit
 +-- Exception
      +-- StopIteration
      +-- StandardError
      +-- Warning
```

Or in code:

```
>>> GeneratorExit.__bases__
(<type 'exceptions.BaseException'>,)
>>> StopIteration.__bases__
(<type 'exceptions.Exception'>,)
```

When I go to the specific description of each exception, I can read following:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.GeneratorExit

> exception GeneratorExit
>
> Raised when a generator‘s close() method is called. It directly inherits from BaseException instead of StandardError since it is technically not an error.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration

> exception StopIteration
>
> Raised by an iterator‘s next() method to signal that there are no further values. This is derived from Exception rather than StandardError, since this is not considered an error in its normal application.

Which is not very clear to me. Both are similar in the sense that they do not notify errors, but an "event" to change the flow of the code. So, they are not technically errors, and I understand that they should be separated from the rest of the exceptions... but why is one a subclass of `BaseException` and the other one a subclass of `Exception`?.

In general I considered always that `Exception` subclasses are errors, and when I write a blind `try: except:` (for instance calling third party code), I always tried to catch `Exception`, but maybe that is wrong and I should be catching `StandardError`.

Comment: I _suspect_ that this is for historical reasons: StopIteration & Exception existed long before BaseException, and changing it might break some old code for no good reason. See [PEP 352](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352) Required Superclass for Exceptions. Note that StopIteration still derives from [Exception in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy), even though that's not consistent with the modern pattern. (I've put this in a comment rather than an answer because it's speculation).

Comment: @PM2Ring that sounds actually logic. Although... maybe there is a hidden reason for this if python 3 still defines `StopIteration` as subclass of `Exception`

Comment: Relevant Python bug tracker link [Issue1537](https://bugs.python.org/issue1537): Change GeneratorExit's base class from Exception to BaseException

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is quite common to use try: ... except Exception: ... blocks.

If GeneratorExit would inherit from Exception you would get the following issue:

```
def get_next_element(alist):
    for element in alist:
        try:
            yield element
        except BaseException:  # except Exception
            pass

for element in get_next_element([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]):
    if element == 3:
        break
    else:
        print(element)

0
1
2
Exception ignored in: <generator object get_next_element at 0x7fffed7e8360>
RuntimeError: generator ignored GeneratorExit
```

This example is quite simple but imagine in the try block a more complex operation which, in case of failure, would simply ignore the issue (or print a message) and get to the next iteration.

If you would catch the generic Exception, you would end up preventing the user of your generator from breaking the loop without getting a RuntimeError.

A better explanation is [here](http://www.algorithm.co.il/blogs/programming/generatorexit-another-reason-to-upgrade-to-python-2-6/).

EDIT: answering here as it was too long for a comment.

I'd rather say the opposite. `GeneratorExit` should inherit from `Exception` rather than `BaseException`. When you catch `Exception` you basically want to catch almost everything. `BaseException` as [PEP-352](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/) states, is for those exceptions which need to be "excepted" in order to allow the user to escape from code that would otherwise catch them. In this way you can, for example, still CTRL-C running code. `GeneratorExit` falls into that category in order to break loops. An interesting conversation about it on [comp.lang.python](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/x1lEcMD43To).

Comment: I find quite logical that `GeneratorExit` inherits from `BaseException`, but for consistence I think that `StopIterator` should as well inherit directly from `BaseException` instead of from `Exception`. It is not an error anyway.

Comment: @ikaros45, the way it is now is probably least confusing with minimal set of `BaseExceptions`. You don't want to add more to the `BaseException` class of exceptions than absolutely necessary because then you've got another one that may fall through your exception handling. So I would agree with noxdafox that the `GeneratorExit` should be removed from the `Base` ones, but then it introduces the runtime if you don't know about it. Hence the current model where it works if you don't know about it but still is not too heavy on the `Base` class of exceptions.

Comment: probably there should be a special ControlFlowException  that is a subclass of BaseException and StopIteration and GeneratorExit should both inherit from it, so that people can explicitly include control flow exceptions without also including KeyboardInterrupt and SystemExit

Comment: This is quite old, but I really need to point out except BaseException or even except Exception is terrible, terrible practice. You should be specific. If you're expecting a StopIteration, then catch only that. BTW I came here to find why GeneratorExit and BaseException have different ancestry.

Comment: @cagney I used to think too that you should catch as specifically as possible, but that doesn't fit the real world very well. I can't tell how many times my code has broken because of an unexpected exception that at the end was to be handled the same way as the specific one. If you're accessing a dict, then sure catch only `KeyError`, but IMO the "deeper" the API, the less sense it makes to be specific. `BaseException` is another beast, and not meant at all to be caught.

Comment: @bgusach no matter the API depth, every layer is responsible for telling the developer and the code *every* exception that it might raise (provided that everything below it works as it promises). If it's really well-designed it will even 1) use its own subclass for every error that it knows it can raise, so that its errors are all distinctly catchable, and 2) give you a single alias for everything it can raise that you can stick into an `except`. If it does that, then any other exceptions from it mean that the whole program *should probably be distrusted and killed ASAP*.

Comment: @bgusach for example, I'd say a great Python module will have stuff `class ValueError(ValueError)` or even `class SelfExplanatoryNameValueError(ValueError)`, and will raise those errors (both directly, and by catching and chaining exceptions). So you can always catch `foomodule.ValueError` or `foomodule.SelfExplanatoryNameValueError`. And if it has a lot of those, it might provide a tuple like `FooModuleError = (FooValueError, FooTypeError, ...)`, so that you can `except FooModuleError` if you really don't see any good reason to get specific.

Comment: @bgusach notice that if a library does that, there is a *huge* difference between getting one of that library's errors, and getting any other error - the first means that your program is still doing something well-designed, the error is being delivered to you controlled deliberately laid rails - the second means that all bets are off, could be a problem in the Python interpreter itself, could be a vulnerability in some library being exploited by a hacker, and so on.

Comment: @bgusach So you're 100% right if you're talking about the kind of error handling where we can't do anything but noisily report error(s), try any cleanup that's safe to try, and then just crash, retry, restart, or move on. And you're 100% right in the unfortunately common case where libraries don't give you the information you need to be more specific. But any errors that justify a different handling action are *inherently* more specific than `Exception`, and ideally any code you call into gives you what you need to distinguish them.

Answer (score 0):

I came here to find the answer myself and found it somewhere else.
There are 3 "special" Exceptions that inherit directly from BaseException not Exception:

```
SystemExit
KeyboardInterrupt
GeneratorExit
```

These 3 are conceptually different from "normal exceptions". They are not an error, but an unexpected external event which you probably don't want to catch. You expect to exit. terminate, stop!

SystemExit, and KeyboardInterrupt are obvious. sys.exit() generates a SystemExit, and ctrl-C a KeyboardInterrupt

GeneratorExit kills a generator that has not iterated all the way through when it's being deleted or garbage collected.But only the generator dies not the whole program.

So what about StopIteration? It's not an error either. Well it is sort of. You asked for next and there is no next. And it obviously must be caught. Otherwise any for loop would generate an exit.

It might seem a bit unfair to call it an error because waiting for it is the only way to determine loop end. But to be brutally bureaucratic: You asked for something you couldn't have. That's an error.